# Customer group form field is not populating in form after save

Tags: magento2, adminform, customer-group

I have added custom field in customer group but after save it is not populating in the form.

I have added field value in `addValues` function in `_prepareLayout` of form like below.but it is not display value in form.

```
// TODO: need to figure out how the DATA can work with forms
        $form->addValues(
            [
                'id' => $customerGroup->getId(),
                'customer_group_code' => $customerGroup->getCode(),
                'tax_class_id' => $defaultCustomerTaxClass,
                'mycustomfield'=>'test' /* this is my custom field */
            ]
        );
```